# Measure the number of lines loaded in l1/l2 cache for reads(including prefetch)?

Tags: c++, linux, caching, cpu-architecture, perf

I am trying to determine the number of cache lines loaded in L1 cache (Processor Intel Broadwell). my kernel code is

`a[i] = 2*b[i] + 2.3 // i from 0 to pow(10,8)`

I am using the perf event `L1-dcache-load-misses`. The measured number is twice than expected. I am expecting 6M loads, and 6M stores. But `L1-dcache-load-misses` is around 12M. However `LLC-stores` is as expected (6M)

***i) Does `L1-dcache-load-misses` count both load and store misses?***

In [Intel software developer manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3b-part-2-manual.pdf) (table 19.5), for L2 cache, I found two metrics

- i) `L2_TRANS.L2_FILL` (r20f0)
- ii) `L2_TRANS.L2_WB` (r40f0)

***ii) What is the exact meaning of L2_TRANS.L2_FILL? Is it the total number of L2 transactions?***

***iii) What is the exact meaning of L2_TRANS.L2_WB? Is it the total number of L2 write transactions?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perf uses these event aliases that map to predefined counter events and masks, but since each CPU may have different mapping, this tends to shift sometimes, and you may end up counting something else.

[This](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/557604) discussion on an Intel forum, suggests that at least some system (Haswell, but Broadwell should be quite similar) had `L1-dcache-load-misses` incorrectly mapped to L1 replacements, which would explain the double value (the stores would also fetch lines into the L1 cache).

As for the L2_trans events, assuming they're correctly mapped, they should indeed count the total fills and evictions from the L2. Note that this may include more that your loads + stores, since L2 also has code (probably negligible in such a small kernel), and prefetching (probably significant since your data is spatially laid out and easy to prefetch).

Comment: I was using the raw mode for L2 events (r20f0 & r40f0). so this should not have the mapping issue right? Also could you please confirm that  L2_TRANS.L2_FILL includes both read and writes. Also I thought L2_TRANS.L2_WB was referring to write transactions not evictions.

Comment: @knightrider - Then you should be fine. I think L2 fill should count stores as well, since they also fetch the line to the L2 if you only write a part of it. WB is usually another name for eviction, so it should count lines written out of the L2 (for example when a modified line is overwritten)

Comment: Normally, a non-modified line does not require eviction if the last level cache is inclusive (which is the case for Broadwell)

Comment: Thanks. One more related question, I could not find RAPL counter mask and event code in Intel manual. If you know the same please let me know

Comment: @knightrider, sorry, i'm not an expect on event masks, I usually just try to look them up in the manual